# Can a level surface $f(x,y,z)=c$ of a function $f(x,y,z)$ have genus 1?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, geometric-topology

I came across this question a few days ago while trying to construct a real-valued function $f(x,y,z)$ whose level surface $A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^3 : f(x,y,z)=0\}$ is a torus:

In general, can a level surface $\{x\in \mathbb{R}^3 : f(x,y,z)=c\}$ of a real-valued function $f(x,y,z)$ have genus 1 or higher?  If so, what is an example of such a function?

Likely because I have no experience in topology or differential geometry, a quick Google search did not provide an answer this question.

Comment: In any manifold $M$, for any closed subset $A\subseteq M$ there is a smooth function having $A$ as it's zero set, as a result of the existence of partitions of unity. You may find this for example in John Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds. However, this function may not be easily described.

Comment: Thank you; this is just what I needed.

Comment: I should add that in general, for a hypersurface $M^{n-1}\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, $M$ is the zero set of a submersion $f: \mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ if and only if it's normal bundle is trivial (a result that can be generalized to any codimension and orientable ambient space). In the case of the torus, it clearly has a trivial normal bundle. You can even give the function explicitly.

Comment: If you just want one simple example as an answer to your ***title*** question, use cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$ on $\mathbb R^3$. In each $\theta=$(constant) half-plane you have a circle given by the equation $(r-2)^2 + z^2=1$. The union of those circles as $\theta$ sweeps around from $0$ to $2\pi$ is clearly a surface of genus $1$. Now convert that equation into Euclidean coordinates using $r = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$.